# Reloading Activity in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

How can I refresh/reload a Acitivity/Screen in Android using PhoneGap. If it is not possible in PhoneGap, how can I do it in JAVA ?

Answer (score 0):

I donot know about PhoneGap. But in Java(Android) you can try this code -

```
startActivity(getIntent()); finish();
```